# Winter Bash's application description still refers to 2020

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021, se-applications

Winter Bash appears as an authorized application in your profile (if you logged in on the [site](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/)). However, the description refers to the wrong website, and the link also could use an update to HTTPS:

[image]

Comment: For anyone going to edit that text: It doesn't support markdown and isn't meant to support that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App description has been updated to use this year's url.

[image]